# Why is this displaying and error ? I have checked over multiple time but nothing works

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I'm getting this Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Dad Task 2.py", line 159, in <module>
    app = window(root)
  File "C:\Users\Ethan\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Dad Task 2.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.LoanAmtAns = self.PriceAns - self.MorDepAns
AttributeError: 'window' object has no attribute 'MorDepAns'
[Finished in 0.243s]
```

Code:

```
    from tkinter import *
    
    
    class window():
        def __init__(self,root):
            self.root = root
            self.root.title("Dad task 2")
            self.root.geometry('500x500')
            self.root.configure(bg = "#c0ded9")
            self.entBoEText = StringVar()
            self.entVarEleText = StringVar()
            self.entIntRatText = StringVar()
            self.entPriceText = StringVar()
            self.entTaxRateText = StringVar()
            self.entDepText = StringVar()
            self.entLoanText = StringVar()
            self.entLTVText = StringVar()
            self.entPriceText = StringVar()
            self.entYearsText = StringVar()
            self.entMorDepText = StringVar()
            # Bank Of England Rate
            def BoEEnter():
                self.butBoEAns = self.entBoEText.get()
                print(self.butBoEAns)
    
            self.lblBoE = Label (self.root,text = 'BoE Rate : ',font= ('Gill Sans', 12),bg = "#c0ded9")
            self.lblBoE.grid(row = 0,column = 0)
            self.entBoE = Entry(self.root,width = 10,textvariable = self.entBoEText)
            self.entBoE.grid(row = 0,column = 1)
            self.butBoE = Button(self.root, text = 'Enter',command = BoEEnter)
            self.butBoE.grid(row = 0,column = 3)
    
            # Variable Element
            def VarEleEnter():
                self.VarEleAns = self.entVarEleText.get()
                print(self.VarEleAns)
    
            self.lblVarEle = Label (self.root,text = 'Variable Element : ',font= ('Gill Sans', 12),bg = "#c0ded9")
            self.lblVarEle.grid(row = 1,column = 0)
            self.entVarEle = Entry(self.root,width = 10,textvariable = self.entVarEleText)
            self.entVarEle.grid(row = 1,column = 1)
            self.butVarEle= Button(self.root, text = 'Enter',command = VarEleEnter)
            self.butVarEle.grid(row = 1,column = 3)
    
            # Intrest Rate
            def IntRatEnter():
                self.IntRatAns = self.entIntRatText.get()
                print(self.IntRatAns)
    
            self.lblIntRat = Label (self.root,text = 'Intrest Rate : ',font= ('Gill Sans', 12),bg = "#c0ded9")
            self.lblIntRat.grid(row = 2,column = 0)
            self.entIntRat = Entry(self.root,width = 10,textvariable = self.entIntRatText)
            self.entIntRat.grid(row = 2,column = 1)
            self.butIntRat = Button(self.root, text = 'Enter',command = IntRatEnter)
            self.butIntRat.grid(row = 2,column = 3)
    
            # Tax Rate
            def TaxRateEnter():
                self.TaxRateAns = self.entTaxRateText.get()
                print(self.TaxRateAns)
    
            self.lblTaxRate = Label (self.root,text = 'Tax Rate : ',font= ('Gill Sans', 12),bg = "#c0ded9")
            self.lblTaxRate.grid(row = 3,column = 0)
            self.entTaxRate = Entry(self.root,width = 10,textvariable = self.entIntRatText)
            self.entTaxRate.grid(row = 3,column = 1)
            self.butTaxRate = Button(self.root, text = 'Enter',command = TaxRateEnter)
            self.butTaxRate.grid(row = 3,column = 3)
    
            # Price
            def PriceEnter():
                self.PriceAns = self.entPriceText.get()
                print(self.PriceAns)
            self.lblPrice = Label (self.root,text = 'Price : ',font= ('Gill Sans', 12),bg = "#c0ded9")
            self.lblPrice.grid(row = 4,column = 0)
            self.entPrice = Entry(self.root,width = 10,textvariable = self.entPriceText)
            self.entPrice.grid(row = 4,column = 1)
            self.butPrice = Button(self.root, text = 'Enter',command = PriceEnter)
            self.butPrice.grid(row = 4,column = 3)
    
            # Deposit
            def DepEnter():
                
                self.DepAns = self.entDepText.get()
                print(self.DepAns)
            self.DepAns = self.entDepText.get()
            self.lblDep = Label (self.root,text = 'Deposit : ',font= ('Gill Sans', 12),bg = "#c0ded9")
            self.lblDep.grid(row = 5,column = 0)
            self.entDep = Entry(self.root,width = 10,textvariable = self.entDepText)
            self.entDep.grid(row = 5,column = 1)
            self.butDep = Button(self.root, text = 'Enter',command = DepEnter)
            self.butDep.grid(row = 5,column = 3)
            # Mortgage Deposit
            def MorDepEnter():
                self.MorDepAns = self.entMorDepText.get()
                print(self.MorDepAns)
            self.lblMorDep = Label (self.root,text = 'Mortgage Deposit : ',font= ('Gill Sans', 12),bg = "#c0ded9")
            self.lblMorDep.grid(row = 6,column = 0)
            self.entMorDep = Entry(self.root,width = 10,textvariable = self.entMorDepText)
            self.entMorDep.grid(row = 6,column = 1)
            self.butMorDep = Button(self.root, text = 'Enter',command = MorDepEnter)
            self.butMorDep.grid(row = 6,column = 3)
            # Loan
            def LoanEnter():
                self.LoanAns = self.entLoanText.get()
                print(self.LoanAns)
            self.lblLoan = Label (self.root,text = 'Loan : ',font= ('Gill Sans', 12),bg = "#c0ded9")
            self.lblLoan.grid(row = 7,column = 0)
            self.entLoan = Entry(self.root,width = 10,textvariable = self.entLoanText)
            self.entLoan.grid(row = 7,column = 1)
            self.butLoan = Button(self.root, text = 'Enter',command = LoanEnter)
            self.butLoan.grid(row = 7,column = 3)
    
            # LTV
            def LTVEnter():
                self.LTVAns = self.entLTVText.get()
                print(self.LTVAns)
            self.lblLTV = Label (self.root,text = 'LTV : ',font= ('Gill Sans', 12),bg = "#c0ded9")
            self.lblLTV.grid(row = 8,column = 0)
            self.entLTV = Entry(self.root,width = 10,textvariable = self.entLTVText)
            self.entLTV.grid(row = 8,column = 1)
            self.butLTV = Button(self.root, text = 'Enter',command = LTVEnter)
            self.butLTV.grid(row = 8,column = 3)
            # Price
            def PriceEnter():
    
                self.PriceAns = self.entPriceText.get()
                print(self.PriceAns)
            self.PriceAns = self.entPriceText.get()
            self.lblLTV = Label (self.root,text = 'Price : ',font= ('Gill Sans', 12),bg = "#c0ded9")
            self.lblLTV.grid(row = 9,column = 0)
            self.entLTV = Entry(self.root,width = 10,textvariable = self.entPriceText)
            self.entLTV.grid(row = 9,column = 1)
            self.butLTV = Button(self.root, text = 'Enter',command = PriceEnter)
            self.butLTV.grid(row = 9,column = 3)
            # Years`
            def YearsEnter():
                self.YearsAns = self.entYearsText.get()
                print(self.YearsAns)
            self.lblLTV = Label (self.root,text = 'Years : ',font= ('Gill Sans', 12),bg = "#c0ded9")
            self.lblLTV.grid(row = 10,column = 0)
            self.entLTV = Entry(self.root,width = 10,textvariable = self.entYearsText)
            self.entLTV.grid(row = 10,column = 1)
            self.butLTV = Button(self.root, text = 'Enter',command = YearsEnter)
            self.butLTV.grid(row = 10,column = 3)
    
    
    
            self.LoanAmtAns = self.PriceAns - self.MorDepAns
            self.lblLoanAmt = Label(self.root,text = "Loan Amount = " + self.LoanAmtAns)
            self.lblLoanAmt.grid(row = 0,column = 4)
    
    
    
    
    
    
    root = Tk()
    
    app = window(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you intentionally have all of those functions nested inside of `__init__`? That is a highly unusual way to write code.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You posted some 150 liens of code for a 10-line problem.

Comment: Why are you nesting functions inside of a class constructor? It pretty much defeats the point of using a class in the first place.

Comment: You could slim your entire code down a lot by having one generic class that has a `Label`, `Entry` and `Button`. The class could have a `callback` argument that gets hooked up to your `Button` `command` and a `text` argument for your `Label`. That way, you only need to define all your `callbacks` and create an instance of the class for each entry that you need. You are doing all of this the hard way ... and a weird way. If I wasn't at work I would give you an example. You would learn a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self.MorDepAns` is not initialized, so the error occurs, however, there are some other issues:

1. `self.PriceAns` should ber initialized as zero if non existant
2. Subtraction result `self.PriceAns - self.MorDepAns` assignment to `self.LoanAmtAns` should be converted to a string.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *


class window():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Dad task 2")
        self.root.geometry('500x500')
        self.root.configure(bg="#c0ded9")
        self.entBoEText = StringVar()
        self.entVarEleText = StringVar()
        self.entIntRatText = StringVar()
        self.entPriceText = StringVar()
        self.entTaxRateText = StringVar()
        self.entDepText = StringVar()
        self.entLoanText = StringVar()
        self.entLTVText = StringVar()
        self.entPriceText = StringVar()
        self.entYearsText = StringVar()
        self.entMorDepText = StringVar()

        # Bank Of England Rate
        def BoEEnter():
            self.butBoEAns = self.entBoEText.get()
            print(self.butBoEAns)

        self.lblBoE = Label(self.root, text='BoE Rate : ', font=('Gill Sans', 12), bg="#c0ded9")
        self.lblBoE.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.entBoE = Entry(self.root, width=10, textvariable=self.entBoEText)
        self.entBoE.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.butBoE = Button(self.root, text='Enter', command=BoEEnter)
        self.butBoE.grid(row=0, column=3)

        # Variable Element
        def VarEleEnter():
            self.VarEleAns = self.entVarEleText.get()
            print(self.VarEleAns)

        self.lblVarEle = Label(self.root, text='Variable Element : ', font=('Gill Sans', 12), bg="#c0ded9")
        self.lblVarEle.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.entVarEle = Entry(self.root, width=10, textvariable=self.entVarEleText)
        self.entVarEle.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.butVarEle = Button(self.root, text='Enter', command=VarEleEnter)
        self.butVarEle.grid(row=1, column=3)

        # Intrest Rate
        def IntRatEnter():
            self.IntRatAns = self.entIntRatText.get()
            print(self.IntRatAns)

        self.lblIntRat = Label(self.root, text='Intrest Rate : ', font=('Gill Sans', 12), bg="#c0ded9")
        self.lblIntRat.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.entIntRat = Entry(self.root, width=10, textvariable=self.entIntRatText)
        self.entIntRat.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.butIntRat = Button(self.root, text='Enter', command=IntRatEnter)
        self.butIntRat.grid(row=2, column=3)

        # Tax Rate
        def TaxRateEnter():
            self.TaxRateAns = self.entTaxRateText.get()
            print(self.TaxRateAns)

        self.lblTaxRate = Label(self.root, text='Tax Rate : ', font=('Gill Sans', 12), bg="#c0ded9")
        self.lblTaxRate.grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.entTaxRate = Entry(self.root, width=10, textvariable=self.entIntRatText)
        self.entTaxRate.grid(row=3, column=1)
        self.butTaxRate = Button(self.root, text='Enter', command=TaxRateEnter)
        self.butTaxRate.grid(row=3, column=3)

        # Price
        def PriceEnter():
            self.PriceAns = self.entPriceText.get()
            print(self.PriceAns)

        self.lblPrice = Label(self.root, text='Price : ', font=('Gill Sans', 12), bg="#c0ded9")
        self.lblPrice.grid(row=4, column=0)
        self.entPrice = Entry(self.root, width=10, textvariable=self.entPriceText)
        self.entPrice.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.butPrice = Button(self.root, text='Enter', command=PriceEnter)
        self.butPrice.grid(row=4, column=3)

        # Deposit
        def DepEnter():
            self.DepAns = self.entDepText.get()
            print(self.DepAns)

        self.DepAns = self.entDepText.get()
        self.lblDep = Label(self.root, text='Deposit : ', font=('Gill Sans', 12), bg="#c0ded9")
        self.lblDep.grid(row=5, column=0)
        self.entDep = Entry(self.root, width=10, textvariable=self.entDepText)
        self.entDep.grid(row=5, column=1)
        self.butDep = Button(self.root, text='Enter', command=DepEnter)
        self.butDep.grid(row=5, column=3)

        self.MorDepAns = 0
        # Mortgage Deposit
        def MorDepEnter():
            self.MorDepAns = self.entMorDepText.get()
            print(self.MorDepAns)

        self.lblMorDep = Label(self.root, text='Mortgage Deposit : ', font=('Gill Sans', 12), bg="#c0ded9")
        self.lblMorDep.grid(row=6, column=0)
        self.entMorDep = Entry(self.root, width=10, textvariable=self.entMorDepText)
        self.entMorDep.grid(row=6, column=1)
        self.butMorDep = Button(self.root, text='Enter', command=MorDepEnter)
        self.butMorDep.grid(row=6, column=3)

        # Loan
        def LoanEnter():
            self.LoanAns = self.entLoanText.get()
            print(self.LoanAns)

        self.lblLoan = Label(self.root, text='Loan : ', font=('Gill Sans', 12), bg="#c0ded9")
        self.lblLoan.grid(row=7, column=0)
        self.entLoan = Entry(self.root, width=10, textvariable=self.entLoanText)
        self.entLoan.grid(row=7, column=1)
        self.butLoan = Button(self.root, text='Enter', command=LoanEnter)
        self.butLoan.grid(row=7, column=3)

        # LTV
        def LTVEnter():
            self.LTVAns = self.entLTVText.get()
            print(self.LTVAns)

        self.lblLTV = Label(self.root, text='LTV : ', font=('Gill Sans', 12), bg="#c0ded9")
        self.lblLTV.grid(row=8, column=0)
        self.entLTV = Entry(self.root, width=10, textvariable=self.entLTVText)
        self.entLTV.grid(row=8, column=1)
        self.butLTV = Button(self.root, text='Enter', command=LTVEnter)
        self.butLTV.grid(row=8, column=3)

        # Price
        def PriceEnter():
            self.PriceAns = self.entPriceText.get()
            print(self.PriceAns)

        self.PriceAns = self.entPriceText.get()
        self.PriceAns = self.PriceAns if self.PriceAns else 0
        self.lblLTV = Label(self.root, text='Price : ', font=('Gill Sans', 12), bg="#c0ded9")
        self.lblLTV.grid(row=9, column=0)
        self.entLTV = Entry(self.root, width=10, textvariable=self.entPriceText)
        self.entLTV.grid(row=9, column=1)
        self.butLTV = Button(self.root, text='Enter', command=PriceEnter)
        self.butLTV.grid(row=9, column=3)

        # Years`
        def YearsEnter():
            self.YearsAns = self.entYearsText.get()
            print(self.YearsAns)

        self.lblLTV = Label(self.root, text='Years : ', font=('Gill Sans', 12), bg="#c0ded9")
        self.lblLTV.grid(row=10, column=0)
        self.entLTV = Entry(self.root, width=10, textvariable=self.entYearsText)
        self.entLTV.grid(row=10, column=1)
        self.butLTV = Button(self.root, text='Enter', command=YearsEnter)
        self.butLTV.grid(row=10, column=3)

        self.LoanAmtAns = str(self.PriceAns - self.MorDepAns)
        self.lblLoanAmt = Label(self.root, text="Loan Amount = " + self.LoanAmtAns)
        self.lblLoanAmt.grid(row=0, column=4)


root = Tk()

app = window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simply that you're referencing `self.MoreDepAns` before you've defined `self.MoreDepAns`. You need to initialize it to something prior to using it.